# Launching an app from our app in hololens

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, hololens

I want to launch one app, which is not default apps of hololens, from my app. I found a solution with URI, but I don't know how to find URI for our custom installed app.
 Does anyone have a suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For HoloLens app, we should use a Uniform Resource Identifier (URI) to launch one app from another app.

The `uap:Protocol` element in the `package.appxmanifest` file indicates the URI scheme name of your app. It should look like this:

```
            <uap:Extension Category="windows.protocol">
              <uap:Protocol Name="alsdk">
                <uap:Logo>images\icon.png</uap:Logo>
                <uap:DisplayName>SDK Sample URI Scheme</uap:DisplayName>
              </uap:Protocol>
            </uap:Extension>
```

The `Name` attribute is the URI scheme name.

If the element is missing from your app, you should first register a custom URI scheme name for the app, then it can be activated when the user launches this URI.

The step-by-step guidance please see: [Handle URI activation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/handle-uri-activation?redirectedfrom=MSDN#step-3-handle-the-activated-event)

Comment: I wanted to reach out to you because of a similiar question. Is it possible to return back to the previous application like mentioned in that [instruction from microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/mixed-reality/remote-assist/protocol-activation)? I develop my app with Unity3d and the instructions given by microsoft for the [uri activation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/handle-uri-activation#step-1-specify-the-extension-point-in-the-package-manifest%3E) are talking about overriding the method `OnActivated` in a `partial class App`.

Comment: I made a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73064585/dynamics-365-remote-assist-on-hololens-returnto-field-not-working) here on SO, but noone answers it, maybe you can take a look. Thanks!